# CouchDB: Manage access rights for databases

Tags: couchdb

I am looking for a way to query and modify the access rights of users for databases.

I found a query to get all users:

https://localhost:5984/_users/_all_docs

and all databases:

https://localhost:5984/_all_dbs

But I don't find a request which gives me the access rights for a user to a special database or let me add a user as "allowed" to a database.

Can anyone give a hint?

Best Regards,
Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way for „given a document in `_users`, give me the list of databases for which this user has access“. You need to check the `_security` - [documents of each database](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/security.html) for a match with a user's `role` or `_id`. If you want to grant a user access to a database, you need to modify the `_security` - document of that database.

So if you build an application with CouchDB, you might want to document the access rights of each user right in the `_users` - DB or in a system database.

And if you don't want to build that logic yourself, you can use a solution like [couch-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@perfood/couch-auth) (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer) or [hoodie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hoodie).

Comment: Can I get the _security if I am no super user?

Comment: No, you need to be a server admin with the `_admin` - role.